# How to pass a List of Objects to a subreport and directly use that Object as a field in JasperReport?

Tags: jasper-reports

On my master report, I have a parameter `ArrayList<Customer>` (`$P{customers}`) and I want to pass that List to a subreport. For now, I am using the following data source expression:

`new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{customers})`

However on the subreport, I want to directly use the `Customer` objects of that List as a field, so I just have a single field
`$F{customer}` (Field Class: `Customer`).

How can I achieve that?